# How to extract right-to-left (Arabic) text from docx using Apache-POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, arabic, right-to-left

I am trying to extract Arabic paragraphs from .docx files. I manged to open it and to read it in Apache-OPI in English, but when the file has any Arabic characters, it will display it as question marks.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FontCharset;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;

public class main_class {

    public static void ReadDocXFile(List < XWPFParagraph > extractor, String filename) {
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph: extractor) {
            System.out.println("Text: " + paragraph.getParagraphText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis;
        File file = new File("C:\\filename.docx");
        fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        String filename = file.getName();

        XWPFDocument documentX = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List < XWPFParagraph > pera = documentX.getParagraphs();

        ReadDocXFile(pera, filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a problem with your console? If you print to `System.out` then you need to ensure that your console / command prompt / terminal / etc is able to properly render unicode characters, is in a font that can etc!

Comment: I tried to write the output on .txt file i have got the same result, and i did try my console with Arabic and it did display it, so the problem in POI.

Comment: @Gagravarr thank you it was the Encoding inside eclipse, but after i fix that the lines are printed from left-to-right how i can change that to right-to-left ?

Comment: You'll need to detect the RTL switch, and tweak your output based on that. The file format stores the text in the order it's written

Comment: I'm not a java fun, In `"Text: "+paragraph.getParagraphText()` if paragraph.getParagraphText() is Unicode, is `+` with String (Non-Unicode) `"Text: "` results a Unicode?